# ember-data issue in bower.json

Tags: ember.js, npm, ember-data, bower, bower-install

i have an ember-cli app which has ember-data in both bower.json and package.json. I was facing the issue

```
The package `ember-data` is not a properly formatted package, we have used a fallback lookup to resolve it at `LOCATION`. This is generally caused by an addon not having a `main` entry point (or `index.js`).
```

I found out that updating ember-data to  [beta16](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3477) or above. So i thought of updating using

```
npm install ember-data --save-dev.
```

This would update package.json to `"ember-data": "^1.0.0-beta.18"`, now in order to update bower as well i did
bower install ember-data --save. Now it gave me options to choose twice which are

1> For this i chose !3

```
Unable to find a suitable version for ember-data, please choose one:
    1) ember-data#~0.0.14 which resolved to 0.0.14
    2) ember-data#1.0.0-beta.14.1 which resolved to 1.0.0-beta.14.1 and is required by text-admin
    3) ember-data#~1.0.0-beta.7 which resolved to 1.0.0-beta.18 and is required by ember-qunit#0.1.8Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

2> For this i chose !3 since i was using ember1.12.0.

```
Unable to find a suitable version for ember, please choose one:
    1) ember#~1.0.0 which resolved to 1.0.1 and is required by ember-data#0.0.14
    2) ember#>= 1.8.1 < 2.0.0 which resolved to 1.12.0 and is required by ember-data#1.0.0-beta.14.1, ember-data#1.0.0-beta.18
    3) ember#~1.12.0 which resolved to 1.12.0 and is required by text-admin
    4) ember#>=1.4 <2 which resolved to 1.12.0 and is required by ember-cli-shims#0.0.3
    5) ember#> 1.5.0-beta.3 which resolved to 1.12.0 and is required by ember-resolver#0.1.14
    6) ember#^1.3.0 which resolved to 1.12.0 and is required by ember-qunit#0.1.8Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

However this only ended up in ember-data becoming 
`"ember-data": "~1.0.0-beta.7"` under resolutions and "ember-data": "~0.0.14" in dependencies.

My Questions:

1. How to get bower.json to update ember-data to `"ember-data": "^1.0.0-beta.18"`?
2. Why is ember-data present in both bower.json and package.json?

Answer (score 2):

You need to update it in both bower.json and package.json. The purpose of this is you don't have to invoke `ember g ember-data` when creating a new project with ember-cli. So in order to update write in both files `"ember-data": "^1.0.0-beta.18"`.

Comment: you mean if i dont include it in bower.json then i will have to do ember g ember-data??? Also yeah i know about writing it, i wanted to know how to get it in bower.json by doing bower install, CLI.

Comment: The one from `package.json` is used from ember-cli as far as i know. So it worked while updating it in both files?

Comment: that i know : ) i want to know WHY?

Comment: I think i've already told you :) see https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2799

Comment: ah right! So the answer to my question "you mean if i dont include it in bower.json then i will have to do ember g ember-data???" is a yes.Thank you : ) Up-vote for that
I still need the answer for how to update ember-data in bower.json using command line after updating package.json ember-data/

Comment: Not in your bower.json.. If you dont include it in your package.json you have to do ember g ember-data. Anyway it's a bit strange why you cant update bower.json. Also make sure that all other ember-cli dependent packages are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but I still think it will help someone. Also ember-data is now upgraded to 1.13.14 as of today.

@wallop: I think you've already got the answer for your second question. For the first question, to install a specific version of a bower component, you can try the following command. It might still ask for the option but I have experienced that it works as you wanted.

`bower install --save ember-data#1.0.0-beta.18`